# rails new ができなくなった

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

昨日までは `rails new` ができていたのですが、本日できなくなりました。

エラーメッセージを読んでみましたが解決できていません。

**環境**

M1 Mac
VScode

**実行したこと**

- `bundle init`
- gem fileを編集
- `rails new .`

`rails new` の段階でエラーで進めません。

**エラーメッセージ**

*文字数制限の関係で後半部分のみ*

```
/Users/tee/Desktop/esf/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/tee/Desktop/esf/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
Tasks: TOP => app:template => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.
You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.
```

**Gemfile**

```rb
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.0.3"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.0"
gem "sprockets-rails"
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"
gem "importmap-rails"
gem "turbo-rails"
gem "stimulus-rails"
gem "jbuilder"
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]
gem "bootsnap", require: false



group :development, :test do
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  gem "web-console"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

また、この状態で `rails s` すると下記のメッセージが表示されます。

何かわかるかたいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

Comment: 最後の方に「 `rails s` すると下記のメッセージが表示されます」とありますが、実際のメッセージが含まれていないようです。質問は後からでも編集できるので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Comment: 編集リクエストありがとうございます!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gemとrailsのversionをあげたら解決しました。。